# code testing tool python

Tags: python, unit-testing, automation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to do a meaningful code-coverage analysis of my unit-tests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1006189/how-to-do-a-meaningful-code-coverage-analysis-of-my-unit-tests)

Is there a tool that displays lines that have been executed (called) and lines that were not executed when executing a specific case so that I know that there are still lines that havent been covered by "this" specific case.

Something like that will be pretty handy in writing robust code. I am sure there is, but I dont know the exact terms to google.

In general, is there a good testing environment for testing the code. Not talking about code that runs on the web (like Django and stuff), just normal coding stuff.

Thanks

Comment: +1, although that seems more like a debugging tool, kinda like the call stack.  I'm curious to see the responses as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using django, have a look at [django-nose](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-nose) which uses the [nose test framework](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/nose/1.1.2) of which [coverage](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/coverage/3.5.1) is a plugin.

You can then easily check the coverage status by running `python manage.py tests --with-coverage`

More info about this [here](http://webamused.wordpress.com/2010/04/07/tutorial-testing-efficiently-with-nose-nose-exclude-and-django-nose/) and if you happen to be interested in setting up an automated builder, if [buildbot](http://buildbot.net/buildbot/docs/current/) the tool of choice [this](http://copypasteprogrammer.blogspot.com/2010/03/buildbot-and-nose-test-coverage.html) might help.

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for code coverage tools. There's some Python-specific discussion about this [here](http://wiki.python.org/moin/CodeCoverage).

Comment: This is little more than a [link to an answer elsewhere](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231/133817), which is discouraged. Posting this as a comment seems more appropriate.